# get a row from a table even if the FK is NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my SQL DB:

[image]

I want to select Libelle_Collection,Libelle_Editeur from all records in the two tables where the Id_Editeur = Id_Editeur_Editeur .

I tried this code :

```
select Id_Collection, Libelle_Collection,Libelle_Editeur from Collection_,Editeur where Id_Editeur = Id_Editeur_Editeur
```

**The is the result I get :**

1 | yyyyyyy | rfer

but it only shows one row where the Id_Editeur_Editeur = 1, I want to show all records even if Id_Editeur_Editeur = NULL.

**And the is the result that I want :**

1 | yyyyyyy | rfer

3 | tytutuyutu | *NULL*

4 | tutyuyr | *NULL*

Comment: Just remove the `WHERE` clause from your query.

Comment: No it will duplicate rows, if I deleted the Where clause it will display me 12 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select Id_Collection,     
      Libelle_Collection,
      Libelle_Editeur 
from Collection_ c
Left join Editeur e
     On c.Id_Editeur_Editeur = e.Id_Editeur
```

Comment: Thanks.. the left Join worked, I didn't knew this type of Join

Comment: @SpoonYukina here is a good explanation of joins -http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html