# dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I tried to add a new row to a Table in an SQL DB, but I had a problem :

> dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables

this is the code I tried :

```
private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
private SqlDataAdapter adapter;
private SqlDataAdapter adapter2;

private void GestionCollections_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id_Collection ID, Libelle_Collection Collection,Libelle_Editeur Editeur from Collection_ left join Editeur on Id_Editeur = Collection_.Id_Editeur_Editeur", myClass.cnx);
     adapter.Fill(myClass.ds, "Collection_");

     adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Id_Editeur ID,Libelle_Editeur Editeur from Editeur", myClass.cnx);
     adapter2.Fill(myClass.ds, "Editeur");
}

private void AjouterBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    String newKeyWordCollectionName = ajoutCollection.KeyWordCollectionName;
    String newKeyWordAEditeurName = ajoutCollection.KeyWordEditeurName;        
    DataRow row = myClass.ds.Tables["Collection_"].NewRow();
    row[1] = newKeyWordCollectionName;

    foreach(var myRow in myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"].AsEnumerable())
    {
         if (newKeyWordAEditeurName == myRow[1] as String)
              row[2] = (int)myRow[0];
    }
     myClass.ds.Tables["Collection_"].Rows.Add(row);
     SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
     adapter.Update(myClass.ds, "Collection_");

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your select query and add distinct with inner join.

For example there are two query from which you can understand that what I want to tell you

Wrong query

```
select iop.pob_id, iop.pob_product_id, iop.pob_qty, iop.pob_unit_id
    , iop.pob_rate, iop.pob_value, iop.pob_fiscalyear_id
    , **p.product_desc** as orderBy from inv_product_open_balc iop
left join inv_product p on iop.pob_product_id = p.product_id
where p.product_desc like 'Air Freshner%' and iop.pob_fiscalyear_id = 3
```

Correct query

```
select distinct iop.pob_id, iop.pob_product_id, iop.pob_qty
    , iop.pob_unit_id, iop.pob_rate, iop.pob_value, iop.pob_fiscalyear_id
    , **(select Product_desc from** inv_product p where p.product_id = iop.pob_product_id )as orderBy
from inv_product_open_balc iop
inner join inv_product p on iop.pob_product_id = p.product_id
where p.product_desc like 'Air Freshner%' and iop.pob_fiscalyear_id = 3
```

Comment: This is a great answer, surprised it doesn't have more upvotes.

Comment: worked fine for me but i didn't need to include the inner join or distinct:
select iop.pob_id,iop.pob_product_id,iop.pob_qty,iop.pob_unit_id, iop.pob_rate,iop.pob_value,iop.pob_fiscalyear_id,(select Product_desc from inv_product as p where p.product_id = iop.pob_product_id ) as orderBy from inv_product_open_balc as iop where p.product_desc like 'Air Freshner%' and iop.pob_fiscalyear_id = 3

Answer (score 5):

You can't use an [`SqlCommandBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) here:

> Automatically generates single-table commands that are used to reconcile changes made to a DataSet with...

The key words here being "single-table". It has no way to reverse engineer from the `SELECT` statement how a specific update should be applied (e.g. if you `NULL` all of the columns from the right side of a left join, should it delete the row, or set each column to null.

You need to author appropriate Insert, Update and Delete commands on the SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

With `SqlCommandBuilder`  you can generate `CRUD operation on entity`

Requirement of use is to define `Select command before inserting` , and include in the select command your `primary Key`.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.80).aspx

MSDN Definition : Automatically generate Transact-SQL statements to update `single table`

Nota : In your Update selectCommand, you defined left join query, and so you can create left join query, replace this query with just select.

Comment: Nota : In your Update selectCommand, you defined left join query, and so you can create left join query, replace this query with just select.

Comment: Left Join query is not single table , you have two tables or more

Comment: I don't want just select statement I must use the left join query, 
check this :  
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632110/get-a-row-from-a-table-even-if-the-fk-is-null)

Comment: with SqlCommandBuilder and left join you can't  Spoon generate your queries

Comment: So isn't there any solution ? because I need to use this left join query to give me the right results that I want

Comment: you want impossible solution Spoon, i understand you why you have bug , i bring you answer about your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add DISTINCT in your select statement with inner join.

This will solve the issue.

like Select Distinct Employee.Ecode, .........