# Error in SqlCommandBuilder class

Tags: database

I want to know if `SqlCommandBuilder` class can set the Insert, Update, Delete option to a database with more than 5 or 6 columns.

When I want to set one of this option to my db it shows this error:

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables

Comment: Can you provide your sample code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639946/dynamic-sql-generation-is-not-supported-against-multiple-base-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question exactly, but just based on the error message you posted -->

MSDN Excerpt:

> Automatically generates single-table commands that are used to
>   reconcile changes made to a DataSet with the associated SQL Server
>   database. This class cannot be inherited.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2