# how to solve "dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables" Error?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I got this error "dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables" in my project.
i got the error on "da.update(dt)" line.
this is the code which i got the error...`so help me how can i solve it..

```
OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = null;
    BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    public void BindData()
    {
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("select t.srno,c.AccNumber2,c.Name,t.Admission_Fee,t.Family_fund,t.MonthlyCollection,t.MonthlyDeposit from transDemand t inner join Customer c on t.AccNumber=c.AccNumber where t.IssueDate=@IssueDate and c.Dismember=false", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IssueDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = datesearch.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        //dt = new DataTable();
        //da.Fill(dt);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdbuild = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Fill(ds, "A");
        bsource.DataSource = ds.Tables["A"];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;


    }

    private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["A"];
        this.dataGridView1.BindingContext[dt].EndCurrentEdit();

        da.Update(dt);

        BindData();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639946/dynamic-sql-generation-is-not-supported-against-multiple-base-tables)

Comment: i want to update only transDemand table..

Comment: Why do you use `OleDbCommandBuilder cmdbuild`?

Comment: try to change  ds.Table["A"] Table name

Comment: For generate single table command

Comment: @muhammad-- i tried it but not working again