# Why can't I use SQLite Command Builder here?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

When I try to click Button1 after making changes, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.'

Now, the error makes sense, so I googled it, and came up with [this Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639946/dynamic-sql-generation-is-not-supported-against-multiple-base-tables).  I tried refactoring my original SQL Query:

```
SELECT T.TournamentName 'Tournament Name', R1.CharacterName Champion, R2.CharacterName 'Runner Up'
FROM SmashTournaments T 
INNER JOIN SmashRoster R1 
ON T.Champion = R1.SmashRosterID 
INNER JOIN SmashRoster R2 
ON T.RunnerUp = R2.SmashRosterID
```

To this, as per the other questions answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.TournamentName 'Tournament Name', (SELECT R1.CharacterName 
                                                     FROM SmashRoster R1
                                                     WHERE T.Champion = R1.SmashRosterID) 'Champion', 
                                                    (SELECT R2.CharacterName 
                                                     FROM SmashRoster R2
                                                     WHERE T.RunnerUp = R2.SmashRosterID) 'Runner Up'
FROM SmashTournaments T 
INNER JOIN SmashRoster R1 
ON T.Champion = R1.SmashRosterID 
INNER JOIN SmashRoster R2 
ON T.RunnerUp = R2.SmashRosterID
```

EDIT: This query doesn't work either, same error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.TournamentName 'Tournament Name', (SELECT R1.CharacterName 
                                                     FROM SmashRoster R1
                                                     WHERE T.Champion = R1.SmashRosterID) 'Champion', 
                                                    (SELECT R2.CharacterName 
                                                     FROM SmashRoster R2
                                                     WHERE T.RunnerUp = R2.SmashRosterID) 'RunnerUp'
FROM SmashTournaments T
```

But I'm still receiving the error when this code is run:

```
public partial class SmashTournaments : Form
{
  public SmashTournaments()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }
  SQLiteConnection cnn;
  SQLiteDataAdapter adapter;
  DataSet dataSetx;
  SQLiteCommandBuilder builder;

  private void SmashTournaments_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   LoadSmashTournaments();
  }

  public void LoadSmashTournaments()
  {
   cnn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\SQLiteDB\SQLiteDB.db;Version=3;");
   adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(
      @"SELECT DISTINCT T.TournamentName 'Tournament Name', (SELECT R1.CharacterName 
                                                             FROM SmashRoster R1
                                                             WHERE T.Champion = R1.SmashRosterID) 'Champion', 
                                                            (SELECT R2.CharacterName 
                                                             FROM SmashRoster R2
                                                             WHERE T.RunnerUp = R2.SmashRosterID) 'RunnerUp'
        FROM SmashTournaments T 
        INNER JOIN SmashRoster R1 
        ON T.Champion = R1.SmashRosterID 
        INNER JOIN SmashRoster R2 
        ON T.RunnerUp = R2.SmashRosterID", cnn);

   dataSetx = new DataSet();
   cnn.Open();
   adapter.Fill(dataSetx);
   tournamentsGridView.DataSource = dataSetx.Tables[0];
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
   adapter.Update(dataSetx); //error thrown here
   LoadSmashTournaments();
  }
}
```

So, does the other answers solution just not work? If not, how should I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Just a typo? `adapter.Update(dataSet);` should be `adapter.Update(dataSetx);` i guess.

Comment: No, that was just a typo in my question.  It is correct in the code.  Thank you for pointing it out though!